# How is the poem “Gerontion” affected by being told in the first person?

Tags: poetry, t-s-eliot, narrator

The poem ‘Gerontion’ by T.S. Eliot is about an old man and his life. The very first lines if the poem are as follows:

> Here I am, an old man in a dry month,
> Being read to by a boy, waiting for rain.

They show  clearly that the narrator of the poem is the old man himself. In some of the well-known poems of T. S.  Eliot it is unclear about who the speaker is, but in this poem it is very clear and above all in first person. Is there a particular reason why Eliot did this? How does it affect the poem?